# String большими буквами

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, я еще новичок.

почему вывод в консоли все ровно с маленькой буквы? я ведь вроде правильно пишу?

PS задача состоит в том чтобы вынести это все в отдельный метод.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String month;
        int monthdate;
        int year;
        month = "november";
        monthdate = 11;
        year = 1995;
        System.out.println(toUppercase(month) + " " + monthdate + " " + year);
    }
        public static String toUppercase(String s) {
            s.toUpperCase();
            return s;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Потому что результат использования метода `s.toUpperCase()` никак не используется и просто выкидывается, сделайте хотя бы `return s.toUpperCase();` что ли

Comment: о, получилось, и правда. а Почему мое не работало, не подскажете?)

Comment: Потому что `s.toUpperCase();` возвращает новую строку, а не меняет `s`.

Comment: String иммутабельный класс, это значит, что его невозможно изменить. Поэтому когда вы пишете s.toUpperCase() возникает объект новой строки. А посредством return s вы возвращаете исходную строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s.toUpperCase();` возвращает новую строку, а не меняет `s`.

```
    public static String toUppercase(String s) {
        return s.toUpperCase();
    }
```